# I need a counter 0 - 99 using two seven segments, and a push button to increase the counter by one

Tags: button, keil, stm32cubemx, seven-segment-display

I need a counter to count between 0 - 99 using two 7 segments and a push buttons to increase the counter by 1 using HAL language in Keil uvision and cubeMX.

I have to use EXTI for the button. When I write my code in the interrupt file it works only one time even if I put it inside a loop. And when I put the same code in the While loop in the main.c file it works exactly as I want.
My question is how can I write a code in the interrupt file to make the button work everytime I press it.
And I only seem to figure out how to make the counter count to 9, how can I make it count after 9 (two digit number)?

This is the code I wrote in the while in the main.c file that works just fine but not in the interrupt file.

```
if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_0)){                   //BUTTON PIN, IF THE BUTTON IS PRESSED
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_9,GPIO_PIN_SET); //TURN ON THE 7 SEGMENT   
        count(ones); // CALL THE METHOD TO START COUNTING THE CASES
        ones++;  //INCREASE THE COUNTER
        HAL_Delay(100); 
}
```

As for the count method, there it is:

```
void count(int n){
    switch(n){
        case 0 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET); //G 
        break ;  
        
        case 1 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET); //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET); //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET); //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET); //G             
        break ; 
        
        case 2:
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET); //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G                 
        break ; 
        
        case 3 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET); //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G 
        break ; 
        
        case 4 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET); //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET); //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G             
        break ; 
        
        case 5 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET); //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G                 
        break ; 
        
        case 6 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET); //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G         
        break ; 
        
        case 7 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET); //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET); //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET); //G             
        break ; 
        
        case 8 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G 
        break ; 
        
        case 9 :
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //A
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //B
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //C
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //D
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET); //E
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //F
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);   //G             
        break ; 
    }
}
```